# drop rows starting with {?[ in R

Tags: r

I want to drop all rows in my df where the row *starts* with [, { or ?

From

```
Value   Phenotype 
    55     [REVERSE223, some randome words   
    22     GENJJS, a string with ? in the middle, not removed
    33     {REVERSE456, this can be whatever
    44     ?GENJKI, a not so long string
```

To

```
Value   Phenotype 
    22     GENJJS, a string with ? in the middle, not removed
```

I tried

```
df <- df[- grep("{", df$Name),]
```

with the plan of repeating that command for "?" and "[" but these three characters seem complicated and I don't know how to work around it.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use put `[{?` inside `[` to scape them and set `invert=TRUE` in `grep`. A very important point is using `^` to indicate the start of the string.

```
> df[grep("^[[{?]", df$Phenotype, invert = TRUE), ]
  Value                                          Phenotype
2    22 GENJJS, a string with ? in the middle, not removed
```

Another combinations:

```
df[-grep("^[[{?]", df$Phenotype), ]
df[!grepl("^[[{?]", df$Phenotype), ]
```

Or more general

```
> df[grepl("^\\w", df$Phenotype), ]
  Value                                          Phenotype
2    22 GENJJS, a string with ? in the middle, not removed
```

Answer (score 1):

> 'So you've got a problem, and you've decided to solve it with Regular Expressions. Now you've got two problems.'

Sometimes it is easier to drop regular expressions and use simple `substr`. This might be easiest here:

```
example <- data.frame(id = 1:4, Pheno = c("[REVERSE223, some randome words",
                                          "GENJJS, a string with ? in the middle, not removed",
                                          "{REVERSE456, this can be whatever",
                                          "?GENJKI, a not so long string"))
forbidden <- c("[", "{", "?")
                                          
drop.rows <- which(substr(example$Pheno, 1, 1) %in% forbidden)


example.clean <- example[-drop.rows,]
print(example.clean)
```

Comment: `which(… %in% …)` is a bit of an anti-pattern, because you can write the same simpler as `match(…, …)`, and indeed this is what `%in%` uses internally anyway. So your code first calls `match()`, then transforms this into a logical vector, and then transforms it *back* into indices. — Either way, I think this is a nice potential alternative but I see no evidence for calling it “easier” than the regex solution: it’s objectively more complex. And the overused jwz quote is just silly.

Comment: Complexity sometimes is a matter of taste. The authors of the `base` package write in the help file for `match` and `%in%`: "%in% is a more intuitive interface..."

Comment: Sure. But not when paired with `which()`. Then it’s just convoluted.

Comment: True, there is absolutely no need for the `which`. I used it, because `which` and `%in%` almost form an English sentence here. Computational complexity will not be an issue with this and even if you can certainly find a drawback when `microbenchmark`ing this has nothing to do with my point, that for many of us it is easiert to think in string methods/functions than in regex, which I consider hard to read and hard to write. YMMV. Make that `example[!(substr(example$Pheno, 1, 1) %in% forbidden),]` if you prefer.

Comment: To be clear, I’m talking about *code complexity*, not computational complexity. Don’t add unnecessary code: small amounts of cruft invariably add up and increase technical debt. The best code is — famously — no code at all. And “almost forms an English sentence” is *really* not good a way to reason about code. R isn’t English, and this way of thinking directly leads to worse code (as it does here).

Comment: Thank you so much Bernhard! This worked perfectly!!

Comment: Great. If it works perfectly for you, pleas consider upvoting or accepting it, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Btw I also upvoted the answer by @Jilber Urbina as this would answer the problem within the regex realm.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, in my reality I constantly find myself in a position where I will report my coworkers that I did delete rows 4, 7 and 8 for some reasons. Or at least where I will confirm the problem by looking into a specific row in the raw data. So that is, why I'll keep using `which` but if that is not your thing, that is fine as well.

Comment: I completely understand what @KonradRudolph is putting across. Notice that the function `\`%in%\`` is defined EXACTLY as `match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`. You can directly type `\`%in%\`` in your console and see that this is the case. Now, in the question, `match(x, table)` is sufficient. You do not need to check whether the indices are greater than 0 just to transform back to the indices. Thats the issue. So rather than using `which(match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L)` simply use `match(x, table)`.

Comment: @Onayambu Thank you for your explanation. So for every not matching entry `match(x, table)` will return an `NA` and I need to be aware that `[` will read `NA` as a `FALSE`. So I will have to keep all of that in my mind to understand the code. On the plus side I spare code complexity but writing `match(x, table)` instead of `x %in% table`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a character class with the special characters in question. Note that `[`, `{`, and `?` are all regex meta-characters; **inside** a character class, however, only `[` needs to be escaped (`\\[`). By adding the anchor `^`in front of the character class you assert that these characters must occur at the start of the strings:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
example %>%
    filter(!str_detect(Pheno, "^[\\[{?]")
  id                                              Pheno
1  2 GENJJS, a string with ? in the middle, not removed
```

Data:

```
example <- data.frame(id = 1:4, Pheno = c("[REVERSE223, some randome words",
                                          "GENJJS, a string with ? in the middle, not removed",
                                          "{REVERSE456, this can be whatever",
                                          "?GENJKI, a not so long string"))
```